# Approximating orthonormal basis in Hilbert space by orthonormal basis from dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Consider a Hilbert space $H_2$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_2$. Consider a linear space $H_1 \subset H_2$ so that $H_1$ is dense in $H_2$. Consider an orthonormal sequence $(h_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $H_2$.
Can I always find an orthogonal sequence $(g_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $H_2$ so that, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$g_k\in H_1$$
and
$$\|h_k - g_k\|_2 \leq \frac{1}{1+k^2}\; ?$$

Comment: You really mean another Hilbert space $H_1\subset H_2$ so that $H_1$ is dense in $H_2$? Since then $H_1$ must be closed in $H_2$, we have $H_1=H_2$. I think you need to drop the completeness of $H_1$.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed removed the completeness of $H_1$.

Comment: I would try to choose a sequence $(g_k)$ in $H_1$ that is really, really close to $(h_k)$, but not necessarily orthonormal. Then apply Gram-Schmidt to the sequence $(g_k)$ to get an orthonormal sequence $(x_k)$ in $H_1$. The hard part is to show, that for the new sequence $|| x_k - h_k||$ is still small enough by showing that $||g_k - x_k||$ is small. It is tedious though, and I am not sure if it works at the end. But I can try it tomorrow, if you don't find a better way.